# Jquery Background slideshow flickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a small script to create a css background image slideshow. The problem is the images flicker periodically and there is know rhyme or reason as to the cause.

```
/********************************
/* HERO UNIT BACKGROUND SLIDES
/*******************************/
$(document).ready(function() {
    var target = $('.hero-unit');
    var backgrounds = [
        'url(/static/template/slides/slide-2.jpg)', 
        'url(/static/template/slides/slide-3.jpg)',
        'url(/static/template/slides/slide-4.jpg)',
        'url(/static/template/slides/slide-5.jpg)',
        'url(/static/template/slides/slide-1.jpg)'
     ];
    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        target.css(
            'background-image',
        backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

        setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    }
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
        target.css({
            'background-image': backgrounds[0],
            WebkitTransition : 'background-image 3s ease-in-out',
            MozTransition    : 'background-image 3s ease-in-out',
            MsTransition     : 'background-image 3s ease-in-out',
            OTransition      : 'background-image 3s ease-in-out',
            transition       : 'background-image 3s ease-in-out'
        });
});
```

Comment: example can be found at http://disalle.dev.activemls.com

Comment: I think the problem is related to the image loading time

Comment: it seams to me that the images once loaded should be cached right? the image are all less than 400k. Is there another approach to preload and cache the images?

Comment: It doesn't load if you just add a string with its URL to an array. It's most likely the case since the delay between images goes away after you've gone through the cycle once.

Comment: @bransonl not sure i follow you there?

Comment: I dont think the browser handles a background image as a normal img tag

Comment: I don't see where you're caching any images so I assumed you just meant your `backgrounds` array. If you reload the website without the cache using `Ctrl + F5` on Firefox and count the number of times it "flickers", it only happens 4 times for me. After that, all images have been loaded at lease once and are cached, making the background change significantly quicker. Also, the `background-image` property can't be animated using `transition`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties. You'll have to animate opacity manually and switch images in between.

Comment: Try creating divs and setting the differents background paths In each one, than replace the elements every time you want to change the background